# Python : How to compare two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
df1

A1    B1
1     a
2     s
3     d
```

and

```
df2

A1    B1
1     a
2     x
3     d
```

I want to compare df1 and df2 on column B1. The column A1 can be used to join. I want to know:

1. Which rows are different in df1 and df2 with respect to column B1?
2. If there is a mismatch in the values of column A1. For example whether df2 is missing some values that are there in df1 and vice versa. And if so, which ones?

I tried using merge and join but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: 1. `df1['B1'] == df2['B1']` 2. can you explain and post desired output as it'd unclear to me what you mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've edited the raw data to illustrate the case of A1 keys in one dataframe but not the other.

When doing your merge, you want to specify an 'outer' merge so that you can see these items with an A1 key in one dataframe but not the other.

I've included the suffixes '_1' and '_2' to indicate the dataframe source (_1 = `df1` and _2 = `df2`) of column `B1`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1, 2, 3, 5], 'B1': ['a', 'd', 'c', 'e']})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='A1', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
df3['check'] = df3.B1_1 == df3.B1_2

>>> df3
   A1 B1_1 B1_2  check
0   1    a    a   True
1   2    b    d  False
2   3    c    c   True
3   4    d  NaN  False
4   5  NaN    e  False
```

To check for missing A1 keys in `df1` and `df2`:

```
# A1 value missing in `df1`
>>> d3[df3.B1_1.isnull()]
   A1 B1_1 B1_2  check
4   5  NaN    e  False

# A1 value missing in `df2`
>>> df3[df3.B1_2.isnull()]
   A1 B1_1 B1_2  check
3   4    d  NaN  False
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to @EdChum (the source of all Pandas knowledge...).

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='A1', suffixes=['_1', '_2'], indicator=True)
df3['check'] = df3.B1_1 == df3.B1_2

>>> df3
   A1 B1_1 B1_2      _merge  check
0   1    a    a        both   True
1   2    b    d        both  False
2   3    c    c        both   True
3   4    d  NaN   left_only  False
4   5  NaN    e  right_only  False
```

Comment: If using a recent version of pandas you can use [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) and pass `indicator=True` to add a column to show whether the row is only in left, right, both

Comment: perfect! seems like just what i needed. slight issue. when i try it on my data i dont see the missing rows. there are a few records that are present in one of the dataframes and they dont show up after the merge. however, your solution works perfectly with the test data that you have provided here. thanks

Comment: any idea why that might be happening? i am reading the data in from some csv files

Comment: You would need to post the data where you are having issues, probably as a new question.

Comment: @EdChum  is there any way to compare multiple columns?

Comment: @JasonLi IIUC you can just take a subset of each df and compare, so using a list of cols you can use the above solution but subset each df e.g `df3 = df1{list_of_cols].merge(df2[list_of_cols], how='outer', on='A1', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
df3['check'] = df3.B1_1 == df3.B1_2`